# Insert html not apply css style

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I made insert html in table list. Correctly that can run. But, It dose not apply css. I tried document.ready or windows.load that can't apply css.

I used Bootstrap and Jquery. This code can't apply css from button.

```
function makeTable(dataList, elId) {
    var id = document.getElementById(elId);

   // Make Button
   var frame = `<td>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning waves-effect" onclick="alert('{0}')">
                     <i class="material-icons">info_outline</i>
                  </button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect" onclick="alert('{0}')" data-type="cancel">
                     <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
                  </button>
               </td>`;

    dataList.forEach( data => {
      var tr = document.createElement('tr');
      for (key in data) {
         switch (key) {
            case 'edit':
               tr.appendChild(new DOMParser().parseFromString(frame.format(data[key]), "text/xml").firstChild);
               break;
            default:
               var td = document.createElement('td');
               td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[key]));
               tr.appendChild(td);
         }
         
      }
      id.querySelector("tbody").appendChild(tr);
    });
}
```

It result under picture.
[image]

Icon and style was not to apply it.

Comment: Can you give us any example page on the CodePen or something?

Comment: I did test other attribute. '.appendChild' It was run.

Comment: I don't understand what "cannot apply CSS" means. CSS applies to all page contents, regardless of whether they are added later on or have been there all the time. Please create a minimum, reproducable example ideally in a runnable code snippet here.

Comment: Also, on your screenshot you seem to have messed up markup in the `Edit` column.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have this css classes on your page.
It doesn't depend on js in any way. Perhaps iframe is used so css is not available.

Comment: I have css file. This page do not use iframe. When this buttons define in the code. So, it was correctly running. But, Insert html, it was can't run

Comment: JS cannot interfere with the rendering of css in any way.
You can make sure like this:
var frame = `
<style>
.material-icons{ color:red;}
</style>
<td>
....

Comment: Maybe i think "new DOMParser().parseFromString" is to wired.

Comment: Please, create example in codepen.io, i will check code .